# Iterate through an array against another, and if true, do something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, if you have a sentence as a string:

```
sentence = "Good morning, i'm doing well today."
```

Then turn it into an array of sub-strings:

```
words = sentence.split(" ")
> ["Good", "morning,", "i'm", "doing", "well", "today."]
```

And you have a WordBank model that has the following record:

```
word_to_find: "i'm"
replace_with: "I'm"
```

I want to be able to iterate through the words, and check against the WordBank.  If returns true, replace that sub-string with the corrected replacement.

```
words.each do |word|
  if WordBank.all.map { \f| f.word_to_find == word } 
    print "True"
  end
end
> True

words.each |word|
  if WordBank.all.map { |f| f.word_to_find == word }
    word == .replace_with
  end
end
```

where .replace_with, I need to be able to call the same WordBank record that returned true, but can't figure out how.

So the end result should return an array

```
> ["Good", "morning", "I'm", "doing", "well", "today."]
```

which can then be put back to the sentence variable as:

```
sentence = words.join(" ")
```

If there's a more efficient way to do this, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Patrick, your question is sometimes referred to as a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You have convinced yourself that to achieve your desired result you need to break the string into words, modify one or more of those words and then join them to get back to a string. In fact, that is not the way most Rubiests would do that. You should instead have just said that you are given a string and want to replace certain words with others, showing the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sentence = "Good morning, i'm doing well today."
wordbank = [ { word_to_find: "i'm", replace_with: "I'm" } ]
wordbank.map { |f| sentence.gsub(f[:word_to_find], f[:replace_with]) }
```

Answer (score 1):

We are given:

```
sentence = "Good morning, i'm doing well today."
changes = { "i'm"=>"I'm" }
```

First construct a new hash:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| k }.merge(changes)
  #=> {"i'm"=>"I'm"}
```

I have used the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block to create an empty hash into which `changes` is merged. `h` is seen to have the same keys and values as `changes` but it now has a [Hash#default_proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc):

```
h.default_proc
  #=> #<Proc:0x00007f80970fe190 <main>:3>
```

As a result,

```
h["i'm"]
  #=> "I'm"
```

as normal (since `h` has a key `"i'm"`), but if `h` does not have a key, say, `"well"`, it is seen that the default proc causes

```
h["well"]
```

to return it's argument (`"well"`).

We therefore may use the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a hash as its optional second argument:

```
sentence.gsub(/[\w']+/, h)
  #=> "Good morning, I'm doing well today."
```

The regular expression `/[\w']+/` matches one or more characters from the character class `[\w']`, namely, word characters and an apostrophe.

---

Consider a second example.

```
sentence = "Good morning,     i'm good today."
changes = { "i'm"=>"I'm", "morning"=>"evening", "Good"=>"Bad", "good"=>"bad" }
```

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| k }.merge(changes)
  #=> {"i'm"=>"I'm", "morning"=>"evening", "Good"=>"Bad", "good"=>"bad"}
sentence.gsub(/[\w']+/, h)
  #=> "Bad evening,     I'm bad today."
```

Among other things, note that the extra spaces are preserved, whereas they would be removed if `sentence` were broken into words, the words modified and then joined.

Comment: yesterday when this question was posted, I found this solution `sentence.gsub(/[\w']+/, h)` but this one is replacing the exact words in that string and rest of them was replaced by empty string. But then I came across your answer here, I found what I was missing here, that is `h = Hash.new { |h,k| k }.merge(changes)`

Answer (score 0):

We can create a wordbank hash and loop over it to replace it without checking since it would only replace word if exists in the sentence.

`gsub` is used to replace word inside sentence since we want to replace inplace we included the `!` version

```rb
wordbank = {
  "i'm": "I'm"
}
sentence = "Good morning, i'm doing well today."
wordbank.each do |k, v|
  sentence.gsub!(k.to_s, v)
end
```

Suppose your wordbank goes over 10000 words and sentence is small then better approach would be to loop over sentence which is splitted by space and replace it word exists in wordbank.

```
wordbank = {
  "i'm": "I'm"
}
wordbank.default_proc = proc do |hsh, key|
   key.to_s
end
sentence = "Good morning, i'm doing well today."
words = sentence.split(/(\s+)/) # splitted with regex to preserve spaces 
                                # which will help to get the same string length
                                # when joined back together
words = words.map do |word|
   wordbank[word.to_sym]
end
```

Note: tested on ruby version 3.0.0

Comment: You might want to add boundaries to your pattern in order to only match whole words.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to modify the elements in `words`, the method to use would be `map!`. Assuming that `wordbank` is a `Hash`, mapping words to their replacement, shis would be:

```
words.map! do
  |element|
  wordbank[element] || element
end
```

Of course it is up to you to implement `wordbank` differently.